# Jest - How do I mock a Service whose constructor takes arguments

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, model-view-controller, jestjs, ts-jest

I have this logic when starting NodeJS app:

```
  const twiddleService = new twiddleService(
    new twiddleClient(),
    new UserRepository(),
    new BusinessRepository()
  );
  const twiddleController = new twiddleController(twiddleService);
```

I've unit tested twiddleService by mocking twiddleClient.

Now I want to unit test twiddleController and mock twiddleService.

In my twiddleController.test.ts file I have

```
import { twiddleService } from '../../src/services/twiddle-service';
jest.mock('../../src/services/twiddle-service');
const twiddleController = new twiddleController(new twiddleService());
```

Obviously this doesn't work because twiddleService expects 3 arguments. I could mock twiddleClient and the repositories again, but ideally I wouldn't.

Basically the goal is I want to be able to do something like

```
jest.spyOn(TwiddleService, 'createBananas').mockResolvedValue('b');
```

So that I can unit test my controller.

What are best practices when it comes to solving this problem?

[Also I'm using typescript]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to import and call `jest.mock` on the `twiddle-service` at all.

Since you are using [Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/140655/3397771) to provide the `twiddleService` instance to the `twiddleController` constructor, your test can supply a simple object - conforming to the Twiddle Service's interface, of course - to the `new twiddleController()` call. You can use `jest.fn` with an `implementation` argument to define what gets returned by the service's `createBananas` method to the `twiddleController` instance. The resulting test would look something like the following:

```
describe("TwiddleController", () => {
  test("calls createBananas method of twiddleService instance", () => {
    const mockTwiddleService = {
      createBananas: jest.fn(() => "b"),
    };

    const twiddleController = new TwiddleController(mockTwiddleService);

    expect(twiddleController.doSomethingWithBananas()).toBe("b");
  });
});
```